# Why PlotRange is not working proporly with ListLinePlot?

Tags: plotting

I have  this code and when I am using `PlotRange` (M.12.0.0.0) it gives me error

```
colorBar[arg_] := Blend[{Red, Green, Blue}, Rescale[arg, {-1, 1}]];
postE = Table[{x, 0.05 + Cos[x]^2, Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 30, 0.05}];
ListLinePlot[postE[[All, 1 ;; 2]], PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y}, 
   colorBar[postE[[Position[postE[[All, 1]], x][[1, 1]], 3]]]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False];  



Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist.
Part::pkspec1: The expression {}[[1,1]] cannot be used as a part specification.
Part::pkspec1: The expression {}[[1,1]] cannot be used as a part specification.
Part::pkspec1: The expression {}[[1,1]] cannot be used as a part specification.
General::stop: Further output of Part::pkspec1 will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

Evnthough I get the result correctly but why this is error appearing? If I remove `PlotRange` it works fine!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In drawing the line, there are values of `x` that are not equal to any of the x values in `postE`. Consequently, use `Nearest[postE[[All, 1]], x][[1]]` rather than `x` in the `ColorFunction`

```
Clear["Global`*"]

colorBar[arg_] := Blend[{Red, Green, Blue}, Rescale[arg, {-1, 1}]];
postE = Table[{x, 0.05 + Cos[x]^2, Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 30, 0.05}];

ListLinePlot[Most /@ postE,
 PlotRange -> {-1, 1},
 ColorFunction :> 
  Function[{x, y}, 
   colorBar[postE[[Position[postE[[All, 1]], 
        Nearest[postE[[All, 1]], x][[1]]][[1, 1]], 3]]]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]